# Java regex - url to test the words after "/"

Tags: java, regex

I have a url as follows:

```
{anydomain}/my-app/test/b5/
```

I want to test that all the characters after `my-app/` which are `/test/b5`  as follows:

`test` - allow everything - all chars including underscore

for `b5` - I am looking for a regex that only allows one number

I have the following in place, but it fails:

```
Pattern.compile("/(\\w()|-)+/(/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/()|-)+(/)?");
```

`/(\\w()|-)` - checks test and works fine

`/(/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/()|-)` - supposed to check b5 but fails.

I need the last part of the regex. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is needlessly long.  Few points:

1. `\w` translates to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`
2. `()` is useless because parentheses are for grouping.
3. `$` denotes a match for the end of input text.

On to the answer. Given a partial url of the format you have there, this will verify your string:

```
/[\w]+/([^\d]+|[^\d]*\d[^\d]*)/$
```

`/[\w]+` is for the first part (test).

`/([^\d]+|[^\d]*\d[^\d]*)/$` says start with `/` and look for either all non-digits until `/$` or 1 digit surrounded with optional non-digits.